# Django multi-model: tracing relationships

Tags: django, django-models

I have a multi model with different OneToOne relationships from various models to a single parent. Consider this example:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    place = models.OneToOneField(Place)
    ...

class Shop(models.Model):
    place = models.OneToOneField(Place)
    ...
```

Regardless if the above model makes sense in real life scenario, how can someone identify if an object of Place has a relationship to any of the other models, in django view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a template, you can say

```
{% if place.restaurant %}
    <!-- stuff goes here -->
{% endif %}
```

The reason for this is that `OneToOneField` entries actually create an attribute in the model they are referencing.  In normal Python code, saying `place.restaurant` where no restaurant is defined will throw an exception, but templates will swallow such exceptions.

If you do need to do something like this in Python code, the simplest-to-understand way is to wrap it in a try/except block:

```
place = Place.objects.all()[0]
try:
    restaurant = place.restaurant
    # do something with restaurant
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    # do something without restaurant
```

**EDIT:** As I say in my comment, if you only want a `Place` to be either a `Restaurant` or a `Shop` but never both, then you shouldn't be using `OneToOneField` and should instead use [model inheritance](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance).

Assuming that a `Place` could have two or more other possibilities, I recommend doing something like this:

```
class Place(Model):
    # define your fields here

    # you could generate this automatically with trickery
    OTHER_MODELS = ["restaurant", "shop"]

    @property
    def relationships(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_relationships"):
            self._relationships = {}
            for attr in OTHER_MODELS:
                try:
                    self._relationshops[attr] = getattr(self, attr)
                except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                    pass
        return self._relationships
```

The above would let you say `place.relationships` and get back a dictionary that looked like

```
{"restaurant": <Restaurant Object>, "shop": <Shop Object>}
```

although one or both of those might be missing, depending on whether they exist.  This would be easier to work with than having to catch a potential exception every time you reverse the `OneToOneField` relationship.

Comment: That's the way to go if there wasn't multiple possibilities for a single Place object i.e. Shop and Restaurant. otherwise you'd have to iterate through every single "sub-model". or am I missing something?

Comment: @msebai: Yes, you will have to iterate through the other possibilities.  If your design calls for `Place` to only ever be a `Restaurant` or a `Shop` but not both, then you shouldn't be using `OneToOneField` and should instead use model inheritance: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

Comment: I guess inheritance makes a lot of sense here. I just need to find out how django will treat this on DB level. Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Restaurant` has a foreign key pointing into `Place`, it leaves a [related name](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) field on the class, so that the pointed-to class (`Place`) can find its contents:

```
# python
import yourproject.settings
from django.db.models.base import ObjectDoesNotExist
try:
  r = place.restaurant_set.get()
  do_something( r.restaurant_field )
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
  print "place has no restaurant"
```

And from a template, assuming you have access to `placeobject` from your context somehow:

```
{% with placeobject.restaurant_set.get as r %}
  {% if r %}
    {{ r.restaurant_field }}
  {% else %}
    No restaurant
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```